# Dynamic Routes in Next.js 14 not working?

Tags: next.js, routes, dynamic

I've established a folder named [id] along with a page.tsx file inside the app/projects directory.

Accessing specific project pages via the typical path convention like localhost:3000/projects/1,
localhost:3000/projects/2,
localhost:3000/projects/3,
and so forth isn't possible.

Instead, you can navigate to the path localhost:3000/projects/[id].

Comment: Please update the above question & add details like Folder structure of your project.